# Google Api Getting new refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, access-token, refresh-token

Is it possible to get a new refresh token using the existing refresh token?

When using the existing refresh token to get a new access token, it only returns these fields:

```
{
  "access_token": "1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "expires_in": 3920,
  "scope": "[scope here]",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

However, eventually the refresh token expiry so how would we get a new refresh token? Would we need to ask the user to go through the initial authorization again?

Or does the existing refresh token expiry date keeps getting updated everytime you use it.

Comment: have you read the documentation for the oAuth provided by google?
[Get an OAuth2 Refresh Token and Configure Your Client](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/refresh-token)

Comment: your link doesnt work but I was looking at this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline

Comment: I misread, it seems like the refresh token does not expire if it is still being used.

Comment: What language are you using.  Can i see the code you are using for authorization?  Depending upon the client library you are using you should be getting new refresh token back every time you authorize the user.    However you dont always get one back when you refresh the access token Google expects you to be saving that and reusing it.

Comment: @ShaunNe 
 Did you find the solution for how to get new refresh token using the old refresh token? I am stuck now. refresh_token generated after the first time authorization is used to obtain new bearer access token but dont know how to get again new refresh token? I dont want the user to authorize for the app again and again.

Comment: @DalmTo pls consider this and provide me a solution.